# Can't include internal JS file in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple .blade.php view for a Laravel application, I'm trying to include a JS file, which is in /public/js directory in my project.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/chartkick.js') }}"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="chart-1" style="height: 300px"></div>
        <script>
            new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-1", {"2013-02-10 00:00:00 -0800": 11, "2013-02-11 00:00:00 -0800": 6})
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It looks like this, but when I try to display this I get

```
test:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined
    at test:8
```

In Chrome developer console, the JS file doesn't seems to be properly included in my project. 
Why?

Thanks for helping.

EDIT :

Here's the file structure

```
public
├── css
│   └── app.css
├── favicon.ico
├── js
│   ├── app.js
│   └── chartkick.js
├── robots.txt
└── web.config
```

Comment: can you check path of file in page source?

Comment: https://mywebsiteurl.com/js/chartkick.js

Comment: where did you put your js file? can you post the directory strucutre

Comment: click on URL into page source, and see if is loading or not.

Comment: I just checked and no it's not loaded

Comment: see, that's the problem, make sure your path is proper and JS file is there.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ asset('public/js/chartkick.js') }}
```

use this

Comment: `{{ asset('public/js/chartkick.js') }}` this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this

```
URL::asset('js/chartkick.js')
```

to

```
URL::asset('/js/chartkick.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one {{ url('public/js/chartkick.js') }}